# Rails throwing Relation#all is deprecated error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated

```
Universe::Animals.wild.types.find { |x| x[:legs] == 4 }
```

Rails is throwing

```
Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published:true).to_a`)'
```

How to refactor this statement to remove the deprecation warning. Dont want to suppress deprecation

Comment: What are the definitions of the scopes `wild` and `types`?

Comment: ```Universe::Animals.wild.types.to_a.find { |x| x[:legs] == 4 }```

Comment: `Universe::Animals.wild.types.where(legs: 4).first`?

Answer (score 1):

1. It tells you!  `you can call #to_a (e.g. Post.where(published:true).to_a)`
2. Don't do that!

```
Universe::Animals.wild.types.find_by(legs: 4)
```

Will fetch one instance of Animals with 4 legs - assuming that legs is a column and not some custom method.